# qt - qml performance

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I am using Qt 4.7.1 lighthouseon my device. When I create a qml application that contain a lot of regular [Text](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-text.html) element , it take a lot of time to load the application(few minutes).
the text is regular text, without special formats or fonts.

I wonder if their is any way to reduce the uploading time , because I want to create a much more complicated qml application, with complicated widgets.

I know that the Qt 5 should improve the use of qml.

Comment: Did you try the QML profiler in Qt Creator?

Comment: Yes, but there is nothig special with this application, just a lot of Text element that place in Loader.

Comment: I noticed that Text elements in QML has longest creation time! It seems to be so expensive and I have some performance issues with it :(

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do to at least show windows, etc, while loading is to use a [Loader Element](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qml-loader.html) and delay the loading of the slower objects till a bit later (after the window is shown, etc).

Also, you might consider using something like a ListView instead of straight text elements, as it's designed to handle the display of large quantities of items in a much faster manner.

Comment: This is exactly what I do. I put gif until the loader finish to load all the element in the qml page....